# How to install fiona?

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

After installing gdal, I get an error even if I install fiona.
os: window10
python : 3.8.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCbpD.png)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an extensive tutorial that helped me. Basically it’s download the `.whl` files from an [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)  and then install it whith `pip` command
https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-installation-the-easy-way-for-windows-31a666b3610f